# Why Bazel with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, 16.10

Assume I installed Tensorflow, but I didn't use Bazel. Why is it recommended to install Bazel with Tf? What are the advantages?

Answer (score 1):

[Bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel) is the build tool required to build and install Tensorflow from source. If you didn't install from source, it's not necessary.